# Undoing some merges/commits, but keeping some

Tags: git, git-revert, git-cherry-pick

I have a bad merge, followed by a couple of good commits. I tried to revert the bad merge, however I do not want to loose these changes (i.e. I do not want a further commit, which undoes the changes), I just dont want them in my branch.

So my log looks something like this:

```
7975c057 | Reverts bad merge
40a01d2f | Good commit
3b2c3825 | Good commit
1f3f1858 | Bad merge - code shouldnt be in this branch
37f71a89 | Good commit
... (more good commits...)
```

How can I remove `1f3f1858 | Bad merge` and `7975c057 | Reverts bad merge` from my branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverting a merge commit is tricky, because a merge has two parents, and the path of only one parent can be followed.  If using an interactive rebase, you would typically have to redo the merge entirely.  For this reason, I might suggest the following strategy:

```
git checkout -b good_branch 37f71a89    # create new branch from 37f71a89
git cherry-pick 3b2c3825                # cherry-pick first good commit
git cherry-pick 40a01d2f                # cherry-pick second good commit
```

This would leave you with the branch structure you want, though the two "good" commits would actually have new SHA-1 hash values, because cherry-picking always creates a *new* commit (though the commits would be functionally identical to their original counterparts).

Comment: When trying to apply the last good commit, I get an error; `Could not apply commit 40a01d2f. hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>' and commit the result with 'git commit'`. Any idea why, or how to resolve this? thanks

Comment: @Klicker The commit was, in fact, applied.  It is just that there were merge conflicts, so a formal commit was not made.  Just resolve the conflicts and then do a manual `git commit`.  Type `git status` to see which files are in conflict.  Then, resolve the conflicts and `git add` those files.

Comment: Checking out a new branch from this commit (37f71a89), seems to loose some commits prior to this one. Should that happen?

Comment: No, that should not be happening.

Comment: Ah, the good commit `37f71a89` was actually a merge, this is presumably why. What I've done instead is checkout from the commit prior to this, re-merge, and re-apply the desired commits. Thanks for your help